# dynamic memory allocation for strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, gets

```
int ReadNames(char ***Names, int *n)    
{    
int i, k;    
char name[100];    
printf("Enter how many names\n");    
scanf("%d", n);       
/* Allocate memory and read names */
*Names=(char **)malloc((*n)*sizeof(char *));
for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
{
    *(*Names+i)=(char*)malloc(sizeof(name));
    gets(name);
    strcpy(*(*Names+i),name);
}

for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
    printf("%s\n",*(*Names+i));
return 1;
}    
void main()        
{
char **Names;
int n, i;
ReadNames(&Names, &n);
}
```

This program is running fine...but there is slight difference from what i am expecting. Problem is when i am entering value of 'n' as 3, it is able to read only 2 strings and prints those two strings....ie. it reads n-1 strings and prints n-1 strings. Anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Four things: First of all *don't cast the return of `malloc`*. Secondly, why not use simple array indexing instead of pointer arithmetics (like `(*Names)[i]`). Thirdly, there's no need for the temporary `name` variable. Fourthly, don't ever use `gets`, use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `getchar()` after `scanf()`

so that each `'\n'` gets disposed of while taking input.
Your code will be

```
int ReadNames(char ***Names, int *n)
{
    int i, k;
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter how many names\n");
    scanf("%d", n);
    getchar(); // eats unnecessary '\n' in the buffer
    /* Allocate memory and read names */
    *Names=(char **)malloc((*n)*sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
    {
            *(*Names+i)=(char*)malloc(sizeof(name));
                gets(name);
                    strcpy(*(*Names+i),name);
    }

    for(i=0;i<(*n);i++)
            printf("%s\n",*(*Names+i));
    return 1;
}
void main()
{
    char **Names;
    int n, i;
    ReadNames(&Names, &n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is most likely because the `scanf` you use to get the count leaves the newline still in the buffer. This means that the first `gets` call reads that single newline and you add that empty line.

A simple and easy solution is to add a space after the `scanf` format, which tells `scanf` to skip all whitespace. Like

```
scanf("%d ", n);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Please Do not use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead.

```
 fgets(name, sizeof name,stdin);
```

remove newline at the end of input.

2.In your case after giving input at `scanf()` you should press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
`gets()` is taking this newline as input for first string.

there are few simple solutions

Use `getchar()` to read newline after `scanf()`

or

Add a space after `%d`  in `scanf()`

or

if you are working on windows you can use `fflush()`

3.[Do not cast result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) because it returns generic pointer and it can be assigned with out cast